# How to vertically stack two HTML buttons without a table?

Tags: html, asp.net

What is the easiest way vertically stack two HTML buttons without a table?

Comment: without tables ? yes of-course .. Table is redundant in your requirement ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't get much easier than

```
<input type='button' ... />
<br />
<input type='button' ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

in your stylesheet, add:

```
button {
   display: block;
}
```

or assign an ID to the element and use

```
#myButton { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways using just html (obviously switch the asp:Button tag for an input="button" tag as you need).

Using simple line break tag

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" text="Button 1" /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Button2" text="Button 2" />
```

Using Div tags

```
<div><asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" text="Button 1" /></div>
<div><asp:Button runat="server" id="Button2" text="Button 2" /></div>
```

Using Paragraph tags

```
<p><asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" text="Button 1" /></p>
<p><asp:Button runat="server" id="Button2" text="Button 2" /></p>
```

Comment: I'd definately choose the <p> option, because it's more semantic

Comment: @jao : More semantic? In what way are the buttons paragraphs? Wrong semantics is far worse that no semantics.